# How to automatically include comments in SSDT generated CLR deployment scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

Once I've coded my CLR function or procedure the SSDT deploy process creates the deployment script and I don't see how to cause the script to contain usage comments.  I could edit the script before execution but editing every CLR in every deployment script is not a sustainable option.
Normally a T-SQL developer would script out the function if they had questions about usage but that tells them nothing about a CLR if it has no comments.

Comment: Could you add them with an extended property? It's not as convenient, but they're pretty easy to manage in the project.

Comment: CLR procedures and functions are dropped and recreated when the underlying assembly is replaced.  Depending on how I've configured the properties they are either dropped with the procedure (gone forever) or (because they exist at script creation time) they are not included in the deployment script.

Comment: Have 2-1/2 years really gone by with no answer?  I don't have the rep to offer a bounty:(.

Comment: Nearly another 2-1/2 years!  I'd offer a bounty by now but there is no CLR code where I now work.